# How to get Java 6 in OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion)?

Tags: macos, java

OS X 10.8 [removed](http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9232566/Apple_tries_to_kill_its_own_Java_on_most_Macs) Java 6 and the [Java Utilities switcher](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-57533880-263/java-preferences-missing-after-latest-os-x-java-update/) and made Java 7 the [default](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58203/mountain-lion-with-java-7-only) jre making it hard for engineers like me who work exclusively on Java 6. How do I get back my Java 6? Note: I tried Google but many of the supposed [solutions](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5559) [are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13520745/how-to-reinstall-java-6-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion) [outdated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/mac-faq.html#revert).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest solution I found is to

1. [Download the jdk6](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572) (download button is on top right)
2. Unpack it to somewhere. Preferably to `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6`. This is what it looks for me:

   ```
   > ls /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6                                                                                                    
   Classes       Commands      Home          Info.plist    Libraries     MacOS    Resources   version.plist
   ```
3. Set your `$JAVA_HOME` to your new location by doing `export JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Home/` before your `$PATH` in your `~/.bashrc` (or `~/.zschrc`) file
4. Prepend `$JAVA_HOME` to your `$PATH` by doing this `export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/us..........`
5. Restart your shell or do `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: I think they have changed the link to the JDK6 that you posted.  it now is a DMG with a .pkg installer.  Now way to extract it to a directory.

Comment: @Amala The installer will use the mentioned directory automatically.