# Install Java JRE 6 (next to JRE 7) on OS X 10.10 Yosemite?

Tags: macos, java

I need to test a web application with JRE 6. I am using a Mac with OS X 10.10 and Java 7 for development. How can I install JRE 6 *next to* Java 7 on this Mac?

[This](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/74813/how-to-get-java-6-in-os-x-10-8-mountain-lion) previous answer does not yet account for the fact (also mentioned in a comment) that Apple's download [link](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572) by now points to a `.pkg` (*Java for OS X 2014-001*) file. Without further knowledge I hasten to install it, for it may overwrite my current Java 7 setup (and may no longer contain JRE 6 in the first place).

Comment: Apple's link is currently down, but this is a direct link to the DMG file: http://support.apple.com/downloads/DL1572/en_US/JavaForOSX2014-001.dmg

Comment: That link is now broken.

Answer (score 10):

`JavaForOSX2014-001.dmg` contains Java for Mac OS X (1.6.0_65-b14-462). It will be installed to /System/Library/Java and /System/Library/Frameworks while Oracle Java is located at /Library/Java. No file will be overwritten.
To avoid any trouble (especially with your $JAVA_HOME/$PATH) consider setting up a Mac OS X VM in VMWare, Parallels or VirtualBox with JRE6 only.

Answer (score 8):

As noted by @klanomath "No file will be overwritten": You can have multiple JDK's installed but only one JRE. But each JDK also comes with a JRE.

Apple's Java integration with OS X provides `/usr/libexec/java_home` that can help you keep the JDK situation straight. That selects among the JDK's and their associated JRE found in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`. See the man java_home page.

However there is no equivalent capability to select among versions of the JRE accessed via `/Library/Internet Plug-ins/` http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202643 provides the only 'official' way to select among those, which requires terminal savvy with sudo and symbolic links. Since you are a developer testing web apps one assumes that will suffice, but not something mere mortals want to mess around with.