# How to launch apps that require Java on Mountain Lion with only Java 7 installed?

Tags: macos, java, eclipse

Just got a brand new MacBook Air which shipped with Mountain Lion 10.8.4 and no Java installed. There is a `/usr/bin/java`, but running it would prompt me to install an Apple-distributed Java 6 runtime in a Cocoa dialog.

However, Oracle is no longer supporting Java 6, and I don't want to be running an unsupported and probably insecure Java installation.

So, I went to [Oracle's Java SE downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) and installed the latest JDK, `jdk-7u25-macosx-x64`. Now the only Java I have on this machine is 1.7.0_25, distributed by Oracle. `/usr/bin/java -version` now works.

I just ran `brew cask install eclipse`, and ended up with Eclipse 4.3. When I first tried to run it, I got the same prompt to install a Java runtime as if I had no Java installed.

So I looked here on Apple StackExchange and found https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/58841/52440. After running `sudo ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk`, I'm now able to launch Eclipse.

However, when I try to launch other apps that require Java, such as `/usr/share/java/Tools/Java VisualVM.app` and `/opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/webstorm/6.0.2a/WebStorm.app`, I get an error that no compatible Java 1.6 is available (see below).

[image: screenshot of error dialog]

Does anyone know if it's possible to get these other apps working, or do they really actually require Java 6 and can't work with Java 7?

Comment: Don't link non Apple code to an Apple controlled place. For eclipse see other questions. Java Vuual VM I suspect is toed to the VM and as in an Apple area needs an Apple VM.

Comment: Java 6 is still supported and Apple provide upgrades. Think of Java 6 and 7 as two separate languages and not an upgrade

Answer (score 3):

The dialog is shown because Oracle's Java has only partial 'JVMCapabilities' set and advertises itself as command-line-only capable.

As a superuser (use 'sudo' if editing in Terminal), you should edit `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk.1.7.[version-and-release].jdk/Contents/Info.plist` and find the following key:

```
<key>JVMCapabilities</key>
  <array>
    <string>CommandLine</string>
  </array>
```

and add it to include the missing values:

```
<key>JVMCapabilities</key>
  <array>
    <string>CommandLine</string>
    <string>JNI</string>
    <string>BundledApp</string>
  </array>
```

After that, you have to either reboot, logout or `killall Finder`, what ever seems to work. (People have reported that restarting Finder was enough, but I had to log out.)

--
[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19594116/50939).